Setting a custom field with value of LeadOrContactOwnerId isn't working in before update trigger but working fine in after update trigger
I am trying to set a custom field (FCRM__FCR_First_Owner_Worked__c) on CampaignMember equals to LeadOrContactOwnerId in certain situations.
I tried it using before flow on Campaign Members but I am getting this error while using LeadOrContactOwnerId in the flow

Assign_First_Ownr (Assignment) - The $Record.LeadOrContactOwnerId field contains a derived value that isn’t supported. In a scheduled or record-triggered flow, $Record doesn’t support some standard fields whose values are derived. Remove the $Record.LeadOrContactOwnerId field

So from here it is clear that I can't use this field in flow.
Then I tried setting it using before update trigger. This time i was getting the Id value in my trigger.
camp.FCRM__FCR_First_Owner_Worked__c = campMemToLeadOrContactOwnerId(camp.Id); 
System.debug('First Owner Worked Value: ' + camp.FCRM__FCR_First_Owner_Worked__c);

When I was creating a record it was showing value in FCRM__FCR_First_Owner_Worked__c field in debug logs. But after checking my updated record it was still empty.
This is my code for trigger
public class CampaignMemberHandler{
    
    public static void assignFirstOwnerWorked(Map<Id, CampaignMember> newMap, Map<Id, CampaignMember> oldMap) {
        Map<Id, CampaignMember> campaignMemberMap = new Map<Id, CampaignMember>();
        Map<Id, Id> campMemToLeadOrContactOwnerId = new Map<Id, Id>();
        
        for(CampaignMember camp :newMap.values()){
            if(camp.FCRM__FCR_Response_Status__c == 'Working' && newMap.get(camp.Id).FCRM__FCR_Response_Status__c != oldMap.get(camp.Id).FCRM__FCR_Response_Status__c){
                campaignMemberMap.put(camp.Id, camp);
            }
        }
        
        // Queried CMs because LeadOrContactOwnerId was null in newMap
        Map<Id, CampaignMember> retrievedCampaignMemberMap = new Map<Id, CampaignMember>([SELECT Id, CreatedBy.Name,CFCR_Created_By_Formula__c, FCRM__FCR_First_Owner_Worked__c,FCRM__FCR_Response_Status__c, LeadOrContactOwnerId FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id IN :campaignMemberMap.keySet()]);
        
        for(CampaignMember camp :retrievedCampaignMemberMap.values()){
            campMemToLeadOrContactOwnerId.put(camp.Id, camp.LeadOrContactOwnerId);
        }
          
        for(CampaignMember camp: retrievedCampaignMemberMap.values()){
            if((String)camp.CFCR_Created_By_Formula__c == 'Marketo Integration User'){
                camp.FCRM__FCR_First_Owner_Worked__c = campMemToLeadOrContactOwnerId(camp.Id); 
                System.debug('First Owner Worked Value: ' + camp.FCRM__FCR_First_Owner_Worked__c);
            }else{
                camp.FCRM__FCR_First_Owner_Worked__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
            }                 
        }
         
    }
}

So I failed again with before update trigger. Then I tried after update trigger which worked relentlessly. There was no difference in my code except an update call.
public class CampaignMemberHandler{
    
    public static void assignFirstOwnerWorked(Map<Id, CampaignMember> newMap, Map<Id, CampaignMember> oldMap) {
        Map<Id, CampaignMember> campaignMemberMap = new Map<Id, CampaignMember>();
        Map<Id, Id> campMemToLeadOrContactOwnerId = new Map<Id, Id>();
        
        for(CampaignMember camp :newMap.values()){
            if(camp.FCRM__FCR_Response_Status__c == 'Working' && newMap.get(camp.Id).FCRM__FCR_Response_Status__c != oldMap.get(camp.Id).FCRM__FCR_Response_Status__c){
                campaignMemberMap.put(camp.Id, camp);
            }
        }
        
        // Queried CMs because LeadOrContactOwnerId was null in newMap
        Map<Id, CampaignMember> retrievedCampaignMemberMap = new Map<Id, CampaignMember>([SELECT Id, CreatedBy.Name,CFCR_Created_By_Formula__c, FCRM__FCR_First_Owner_Worked__c,FCRM__FCR_Response_Status__c, LeadOrContactOwnerId FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id IN :campaignMemberMap.keySet()]);
        
        for(CampaignMember camp :retrievedCampaignMemberMap.values()){
            campMemToLeadOrContactOwnerId.put(camp.Id, camp.LeadOrContactOwnerId);
        }
         
        List<CampaignMember> cmToUpdate = new List<CampaignMember>();
        for(CampaignMember camp: retrievedCampaignMemberMap.values()){
            if((String)camp.CFCR_Created_By_Formula__c == 'Marketo Integration User'){
                camp.FCRM__FCR_First_Owner_Worked__c = campMemToLeadOrContactOwnerId(camp.Id); 
                System.debug('First Owner Worked Value: ' + camp.FCRM__FCR_First_Owner_Worked__c);
            }else{
                camp.FCRM__FCR_First_Owner_Worked__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
            }
            cmToUpdate.add(camp);
        }
        
        if (!cmToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            update cmToUpdate;
        }
    }
}

There are few things I found about LeadOrContactOwnerId field.

This field is a polymorphic relationship field (I don't know how that can cause any issues)
This field is a derived field which might cause some problems.

What i want to understand is

Why this is working fine in after update trigger and isn't working in before update trigger.
If debug logs for FCRM__FCR_First_Owner_Worked__c was showing Id in it why it wasn't being set.

I can confirm that there is nothing else which could update the field except my trigger.

Any chance this trigger could be running multiple times, and possibly wiping out an ID value populated into that field on the first run? Might be a longshot, but try putting another debug log in the ELSE  block to see if that's being executed at any point, and what the value might be. Side note- You should be able to combine those last 2 FOR loops into one, and also loop directly through the query as opposed to storing it in the map. Would be the same result, but less code and slightly more efficient.
